# How to properly serialize a class in VB.NET? (bug in my code, probably...)

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization

What's wrong with my code that TRIES to serialize a simple (Big, but simple) class in XML?

```
Public Function SerializeRSPar() As String

    Try

        Dim RS As New BASE_RSPar
        RS = RSPar

        Dim xml_serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(BASE_RSPar))
        Dim string_writer As New StringWriter
        xml_serializer.Serialize(string_writer, RSPar)
        Return string_writer.ToString()

    Catch E As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(E.Message)
    End Try

End Function

Public Class BASE_RSPar

    Property Spid As Integer
    Property ColoreQtaUgualeEvasa As Integer
    Property ColoreQtaMinoreEvasa As Integer
    Property ColoreQtaMaggioreEvasa As Integer
    Property SistemaCalcoloProvvigioni As Integer

    ...
    ...

End Class
```

Problem is that it keeps gving me the error: "SGS.mdlClassi non è accessibile a causa del livello di protezione impostato. È possibile elaborare solo i tipi pubblici."

Hm... Ok, in English:"SGS.MdlClassi is not accessible because of the propection level. Only public types can be processed"

Note: Both the Function AND the Class are in the same module

...Help? Please?

Comment: What is `SGS.mdlClassi`? Where does `RSPar` come from? Shouldn't you pass this reference as an argument in your method (defined as `SerializeRSPar(ByVal RSPar as BASE_RSPar)`)?

Comment: Well, SGS.mdlClassi is the name of the module where both function and class are, RsPar is an instance of the BASE_RSPar class... And I am going nuts...

Comment: Please show us your module's declaration. I have a feeling this might simply be a matter of changing `Module mdlClassi` to `Public Module mdlClassi`.